# Sabre Dev Studio Contact Response

Tags: sabre

Does Sabre Dev Studio have a phone contact (not eServices)? If not how long does it take for them to reply to a contact request from the site?

More than 24 hours for a response is unacceptable for the amount of money that is dished out for this type of access. Also would it be too much to ask for confirmation and response emails to let folks know that they have at least received the support request much like every other technical support provider.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried webservices.support@sabre.com quoting your IPCC / PCC? - Usually < 24 hour turnaround for me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sabre Holdings - Global Customer Support Center

800-678-9460 ( USA)

682-605-5570 (Canada)

598-2-518-6020 (Intl)

Although I usually just drop an email to webservices.support@sabre.com quoting our IPCC / PCC. Depending on which timezone you're in it should be < 24 hours response.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the webservices email. I tried the global customer support and they just directed me back to the website.

Comment: That worked, they actually got back to me via the email address above within a few hours.